# How to convert one date format to another

Tags: javascript, date

Convert `20-JAN-2012` into `01/20/2012`. The solution should work in IE and FF latest versions.

Comment: -1 for not showing any research effort.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those specific formats

```
var a = '20-JAN-2012'.toUpperCase().split("-");
a[1] = (("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC".indexOf(a[1]) / 3 + 101) + "").substr(1);
alert( a[1] + "/" + a[0] + "/" + a[2] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider usage of [Datejs library](http://www.datejs.com/) which is really great.

Answer (score 0):

// Seems a lot of work for just one date.

```
function convertJAN202012(){
    var A= [], monthnames={
        JAN:'01'
    },
    string= '20-JAN-2012';
    A= string.split('-');
    if(A[0]<10)A[0]='0'+A[0];
    return [monthnames[A[1]], A[0], A[2]].join('/');
}
convertJAN202012()

/*  returned value: (String)
01/20/2012
*/
```